# mount a drive on Mac OS X with bash script (and NOT use expect)

Tags: macos, bash, expect, mount, samba

I'd like to mount a Samba drive in OS X using bash. This line does the trick:

```
mount -t smbfs //$SAMBAUSER@$ADRESS/$NAMEOFSHARE $MACOSXPATH
```

only one problem. I want it done without user input - which means no password can be manually put in. And I'm not going to ask my users to download fink just so they can install expect (as seen [here](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20021126055408382)).

I tried applying the accepted solution to a similar StackOverflow problem shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150882/how-to-automatically-add-user-account-and-password-with-a-bash-script) by doing this:

```
echo "mypassword" | mount -t smbfs //$SAMBAUSER@$ADRESS/$NAMEOFSHARE $MACOSXPATH --stdin
```

but no luck - that doesn't work and Mac OS X tells me I used mount command improperly:

```
usage: mount [-dfruvw] [-o options] [-t ufs | external_type] special node
   mount [-adfruvw] [-t ufs | external_type]
   mount [-dfruvw] special | node
```

Any suggestions? This would be easy with an expect script - but that would ruin the user experience to have that prerequisite in my mind.

Answer (score 4):

If `mount(8)` can't just call the `mount` syscall on the filesystem, it looks for a program to help it.  On FreeBSD and Mac OS X, those helper programs follow the naming convention `mount_XXX`, where `XXX` is the `-t` argument's value.

That means you want to check the `mount_smbfs(8)` [man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/mount_smbfs.8.html), which tells us about `-N`:

```
-N    Do not ask for a password.  At run time, mount_smbfs reads the ~/Library/Preferences/nsmb.conf
      file for additional configuration parameters and a password.  If no password is found,
      mount_smbfs prompts for it.
```

Unfortunately the man page trail ends with one for `nsmb.conf` that doesn't [mention anything about storing passwords](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man5/nsmb.conf.5.html).  On FreeBSD 8.0, at least, the solution is [to put a `password` key with a plain text(!) password value under a `[SERVER:USER]` heading](http://forums.freebsd.org/showthread.php?t=1252).  That would be type `C` according to the linked `nsmb.conf` man page.

So it seems that you'll want to dump a pre-configured `nsmb.conf` into your user's `~/Library/Preferences/` directory and then call your `mount` command with `-N`.  As far as I know you can't provide a hashed value, which is not especially awesome.  I'll try to get access to a MacBook in a few hours to test this.

**NB**: This is *not* how to do it with the GNU toolchain.  If you're on Linux, you're probably going to be using something like `mount.cifs(8)`.  The correct solution in *that* case is the `credentials=filename` option (used after `-o`, of course), where `filename` is a file of credentials in `key=value` form, separated by newlines.  See http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount.cifs

Answer (score 4):

The answer in [this apple support discussion thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5900131?tstart=0) worked for me:

```
osascript -e 'mount volume "smb://user:password@server/share"'
```

Answer (score 2):

I'll give you 2 options.  First, include the password on the command line:

```
mount -t smbfs //$SAMBAUSER:$PASSWORD@$ADRESS/$NAMEOFSHARE $MACOSXPATH
```

This is not a great option because the command line (including password) is visible to anyone who happens to be logged in at the moment.  Not great, but it is a possibility.

Second, use expect.  The [Mac OS X Hints article you linked](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20021126055408382) dates from 2002, when OS X v10.2 would've been current.  While 10.2 apparently didn't include expect as a standard component, 10.6 does, and I'm pretty sure it's been included for several versions now.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn mount -t smbfs //fred@12.34.56.78/myfiles /tmp/mountpoint
expect "Password:"
send "wibble\r"
wait
```

Comment: absolutely. thanks! I just used the first for simplicity. I do wonder about expect though - I couldn't seem to find any resources about which version it started being included on Mac OS X....

Comment: just out of curiosity - the expect script does not work. I tried it with `sudo expect script-name` and it just echoed the line `spawn mount -t smbfs //fred@12.34.56.78/myfiles /tmp/mountpoint` (except with real values of course) and then prompted me for my password....what went wrong?

Comment: It sounds like the `expect "Password:"` isn't matching properly against the prompt.  Try running it with `sudo expect -d ./ts` to get a debug-mode narration of what's happening as it runs.

Answer (score 0):

You not only can use a hashed value, you're expected to, at least in older releases. The crypt option for smbutil is not DOD-level security but as with most security, you're trying to keep the honest people honest: the bent ones will find a way. It seems to be broken in Mountain Lion but the nsmb.conf file in ~/Library/Preferences should be secure at the OS level. The /etc/nsmb.conf would override it if it exists. I'm sure there's a reason why plain text files are obsolete but didn't we go this with NetInfo? How long did it take for Apple to allow the old standbys (/etc/hosts, /etc/passwd) to be used?