# Bulk Assign Multiple Users to Multiple Groups

Tags: linux, bash, fedora

I have 2 text files, users.txt with a list of 1000 users and groups.txt with a list of 50 groups. I want to run a command that adds 30 users to each group (ex: users 1-30 to group 1, users 31-60 to group 2, etc.). What would be the most practical way of doing this?

This is what I have so far:

```
for i in `cat users.txt` ; do useradd $i; echo Pass$i | passwd $i -- stdin; done
for i in `cat groups.txt` ; do groupadd $i; done
```

Comment: You will get better help if you show what you have done so far, and explained the specific problems you are having. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your files have one user and one group per line, here's a pseudo-oneliner:

```
sed = groups.txt | while true ; do 
  read line_no
  read group_name
  [ -z $line_no ] && break
  (( from = (line_no - 1) * 30 + 1 ))
  (( to = line_no * 30 ))
  sed -n "${from},${to} p" users.txt | xargs -r -n 1 usermod -a -G $group_name 
done
```

This code calls `sed(1)` to print line number (starting with 1) and the line itself (i.e. the group name) for each line in `groups.txt`, then pipes that output into an endless loop, which does the following:

- Reads line number from the piped input into `$line_no` variable
- Reads group name from the piped input into `$group_name` variable
- If `$line_no` is empty, assumes we've reached an end of `groups.txt` and break-exits the loop
- Calculates starting and ending line numbers for `users.txt` using `$line_no` as index
- Calls `sed(1)` to print all lines from `users.txt` between those lines
- That list of usernames is piped into `xargs(1)`, which runs `usermod(8)` for each single username, appending it to a `$group_name` from above. `'-r'` switch tells `xargs(1)` to not run `usermod(8)` if the username/stdin is empty.

*edit: replaced semicolons with line breaks for legibility*

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. Just to be clear though, if I want to set passwords to each user, should I run the commands I already have (in my edits to the original post) or is there a way to assign a password (could be random) in this script?

Comment: Use [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150882/how-to-automatically-add-user-account-and-password-with-a-bash-script#comment39304417_2151149) to change passwords non-interactively.